# Angular (2) Server side form validation (and best practices)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am having problems for implementing a simple server side form validation using angular 2.

given the following scenario:

- Simple form with login and password fields. (attached to the components view through ngForm / ngModel directives)
- Template based form
- Using Synchronous validation
- Server response JSON object has the following shape `{field: error}` 
  e.x, if login and password are empty response is:  `{login: 'required', password: 'required'}`

Once it is submitted I have the response from server but I don't know how to update the state of each ngModel bound to a view control element to show it in the UI

It is a very common scenario and I am surprised that I am experiencing so many troubles of finding a proper documentation. (client validation is very well explained on the other hand)

Any help appreciated! 
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking all over the internet for server-side validation models, and i haven't find any official documentation, but instead, i got some useful articles - one of them from Stack Over~ - which may help you a little. I have not tested yet, still looking for infos and maybe you have already found an answer for your problem. Anyway, here is a short list with articles about server-side validations using different API:

https://www.carlrippon.com/integrating-validation-in-angular-2-and-asp-net-core/

https://www.puzzle.ch/blog/articles/2017/01/18/server-side-validations-with-angular-2

[Angular 2 (Beta) Server side validation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280787/angular-2-beta-server-side-validation-messages)